# Python django. How can I enter the text selected by the user with a drop-down element in the name_znat field

Tags: python, html, django

There is an html form with dropdown elements:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "{% url 'create_group_handler'%}">
<select name = "select"> <! - Add an identifier here instead of using 'name' ->
<option value = "value1"> Value 1 </ option>
<option value = "value2" selected> Value 2 </ option>
<option value = "value3"> Value 3 </ option>
</ select>
</ form>
```

And there is a Python django model:

```
Znat Class (models.Model):
 name_znat = models.CharField ('Name znat', max_length = 200)
```

Suppose that the user selects a drop-down element with the text "Value 2".
How can I enter the text selected by the user with a drop-down element in the `name_znat` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the select box value by using `request.POST.get` where all the submitted data is.

views.py

```
def myview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        selected_option = request.POST.get('select')
        Znat.objects.create(name_znat=selected_option)
    return redirect("/")
```

Also you should have `{% csrf_token %}` whenever you're using forms. Unless your view has been explicitly been marked as `csrf_exempt`. You can read about the [importance of CSRF Tokens here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/)

```
<form method = "POST" action = "{% url 'create_group_handler'%}">
{% csrf_token %}
<select name = "select"> <! - Add an identifier here instead of using 'name' ->
<option value = "value1"> Value 1 </ option>
<option value = "value2" selected> Value 2 </ option>
<option value = "value3"> Value 3 </ option>
</ select>
</ form>
```

Comment: Does not work. The value is written as NullDoes not work. The value is written as Null

Comment: html:
<form method = "POST" action = "{% url 'create_group_handler'%}">
{% csrf_token %}
<select name="select"> 
<option value= "value1"> Value 1 </option>
<option value="value2" selected> Value 2 </option>
<option value="value3"> Value 3 </option>
</select>
</ form>
views.py:

selected_option = request.POST.get('select')
profile = Znat(name_znat = selected_option)
profile.save()
if profile is None:
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/none')
else:
   return HttpResponseRedirect('../')

Comment: But how to do it ?
If I'm writing something wrong, then I apologize, I'm from Russia, I use a translator

Comment: what's the output of `print(selected_option)`

Answer (score 1):

Use ModelForm, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms. Makes maximum use of Django's built-in capabilities. Good luck!

models.py:

```
class Znat (models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('value1', 'Value 1'),
        ('value2', 'Value 2'),
        ('value3', 'Value 3'),
    )
    name_znat = models.CharField ('Name znat', max_length = 200, choices=CHOICES)
```

forms.py:

```
class CreateZnatForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Znat
        fields = ('name_znat')
        widgets = {
            'name_znat': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

views.py:

```
class ZnatCreate(CreateView):
    model = Znat
    fields = ['name_znat']
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('znat/', ZnatCreate.as_view(), name='create_group_handler'),
]
```